# Wordpress Simple Shopping Cart

Tags: php, wordpress

i need WordPress shopping cart function with or without any pluggins. When a registered user click the add to cart button on the normal post, it needs to go to shopping cart. The checkout function should not have the shipping and payment gateways as the user click the check out button he should recieve the mail for order confirmation with the permalinks of the post bought by him, meanwhile the post permalinks has to be saved in data base which can be viewed by the user later. Admin should recieve the mail for perchasing order.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/). Its a wordpress e commerce plugin and should take care of all the things you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks but i have tried it, it wont work or i don't know how to disable shipping and payment gateway. please help me if you know.

Comment: @kamaal - i have not developed on wordpress. I just know that this plugin exists.

Answer (score 0):

Salman, Try [WP e-Commerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) one of my favorite and o.s plugin

For more http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/top-5-excellent-e-commerce-plugins-for-wordpress/

Comment: thanks man but my problem is i don't want shipping and payment gateway, i dont know how to completely skip this two steps.
* All i need: when user click checkout it just confirm the order and checking out without any payment or shipping pages. please help me.

Comment: @kamaal  WP e-Commerce  have facility like pay with DD, check. Its a manual process.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a simple cart other than Wordpress integrated plugin, you can go for OpenCart, which was easily administrate and user friendly with analytics and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to similar question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16576/shopping-cart-without-checkout).

In addition - the [WP Order Cart](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-order-cart/) plugin does not save orders to database, it only sends the order email to both buyer and seller - this functionality is still in development.